# Which groups contain a comb?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

The *comb* is the undirected simple graph with nodes
$\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$
where $\mathbb{N} \ni 0$ and edges
$$ \{\{(m,n), (m,n+1)\}, \{(m,0), (m+1,0)\} \;|\; m \in \mathbb{N}, n \in \mathbb{N}\} $$

Let $G$ be a discrete group. Say that $G$ *contains a comb* if there exists a finite set $S \not\ni 1_G$ such that the comb is a subgraph of the (simple undirected) Cayley graph $\mathrm{Cay}(\langle S \rangle, S)$.

I don't require spanning or induced subgraphs, just plain subgraphs. I don't require anything involving "Lipschitz", the teeth $\{n\} \times \mathbb{N}$ may get close to each other whenever they like, just not intersect each other or themselves.

> Suppose $G$ is not locally virtually cyclic. Does it necessarily contain a comb?

One can equivalently restrict to f.g. groups and require that $\mathrm{Cay}(G, S)$ directly contains the comb (and drop the "locally").

In case the answer is "no" (or is hard to solve), I also state a quantitative version of this below.

If $G$ is f.g. and not virtually cyclic then $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S)$ contains infinitely many vertex-disjoint paths for some finite generating set $S$. By joining these rays, we obtain that every group that is not locally virtually cyclic contains a comb with some co-infinite set of ``teeth'' removed. (This is more or less Halin's grid theorem, see discussion and follow references of http://www.dim.uchile.cl/~mstein/domin.pdf .)

Let $T \subset \mathbb{N}$ be an infinite set. The *$T$-comb* is the undirected simple graph with nodes $(T \times \mathbb{N}) \cup (\mathbb{N} \times \{0\})$ and edges
$$ \{\{(t,n), (t,n+1)\}, \{(m,0), (m+1,0)\} \;|\; m \in \mathbb{N}, t \in T, n \in \mathbb{N}\} $$

> Can something be said about the ``maximal density'' of $T \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $G$ contains an $T$-comb? (E.g. can we pick $T$ to be the values of a fixed polynomial.)

Some thoughts of mine, not very polished:

- By compactness arguments and changing the generators, it is easy to see that the question stays equivalent if we assume that the comb has a two-sided spine or two-sided teeth, i.e. we can replace one or both of the $\mathbb{N}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, and similarly containing a $T$-comb for syndetic $T \subset \mathbb{N}$ is equivalent to containing a comb.
- Any nonamenable group contains a comb, because it even contains a binary tree [Trees in groups of exponential growth](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60011/trees-in-groups-of-exponential-growth)
- Any Cayley graph of an infinite f.g. group contains bi-infinite paths, so if $G$ has an infinite quotient $H$ whose kernel is not locally finite (i.e. $G$ is f.g. and ``(not locally finite)-by-infinite'') then it contains a comb. For this, pick an infinite path in both $H$ and $K$ w.r.t. some generators. Lift the path from $H$ arbitrarily to $G$ (include preimages for generators of $G$ in the generating set $S$ of $G$), and everywhere on this path, start another path in the kernel direction.
- For solvable groups, the answer is "yes": Among f.g. groups, solvable groups of exponential growth contain a binary tree (see the MO link above), solvable groups of subexponential growth are virtually nilpotent by Milnor-Wolf, and to a virtually nilpotent group you can e.g. apply the previous observation (if a group contains a subgroup containing a comb it contains a comb, and all subgroups of a virtually nilpotent group are finitely generated). I don't know if there's an easy argument for elementary amenable groups.
- One thing that seems obvious to try (but I don't have the chops) is to take a bi-infinite geodesic in $G$ (path where all finite subpaths of length $n$ join group elements at distance $n$ in the Cayley graph), and start random walks every $k$ steps for some $k$, which (I'm told) diverge almost surely on all groups with growth faster than $n^2$ (and in the unsolved case the growth is superpolynomial). Perhaps for large enough $k$ you can use Lovász local lemma or something to prove that these do not necessarily hit each other.

Comment: Discussed with a colleague, who asked if the Grigorchuk group contains a comb (since he first thought my definition required straight teeth). Anyway: the Grigorchuk group is a branch group, so it contains a non-trivial product of infinite f.g. groups, and you can apply the third observation above. So it contains a comb.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the usual suspects and seems that [Chou, Ching. Elementary amenable groups. Illinois J. Math. 24 (1980), no. 3, 396--407. doi:10.1215/ijm/1256047608. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256047608] solves the elementary amenable case. I don't know if I should just modify my question since this is not an answer, but here goes.

> Theorem 3.2'. A finitely generated group in $EG$ is either almost nilpotent or it contains a free subsemigroup on two generators.

Here, $EG$ is the class of elementary amenable group, i.e. the smallest class of groups which contains all finite groups and all abelian groups and is closed under group extensions and direct unions. *Almost nilpotent* is what I called virtually nilpotent in my question, i.e. has a nilpotent subgroup of finite index (here necessarily f.g.). Then apply the third and fourth item from my question, details below though probably obvious to experts if correct.

> Theorem. Let $G$ be an elementary amenable group which is not locally virtually cyclic. Then $G$ contains a comb.

Proof: W.l.o.g. $G$ is a finitely-generated group that is not virtually cyclic. If $G$ contains a free subsemigroup on two generators, we are done. Otherwise, by Chou's theorem it is virtually nilpotent. So we show that if $G$ is a virtually nilpotent group then either $G$ is virtually cyclic or it contains a comb.

For this, for a contradiction suppose $G$ is nilpotent of minimal nilpotency class among those nilpotent groups that are not virtually cyclic and do not contain a comb. It is well-known that the commutator subgroup $[G, G]$ is finitely generated (f.g. nilpotent $\implies$ polycyclic $\implies$ maximal condition on subgroups), and of course it is nilpotent of smaller nilpotency class. If it is not virtually cyclic, then it contains a comb by the inductive assumption, thus so does $G$, so we may assume $[G, G]$ is virtually cyclic.

If $[G, G]$ is finite, then the abelianization $G/[G, G]$ cannot be virtually cyclic or $G$ would also be virtually cyclic ($\mathbb{Z}$ is a free group, just pick a section), and thus by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups $G/[G, G]$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, thus a comb. It follows that $[G, G]$ must be virtually $\mathbb{Z}$. If the abelianization $G/[G, G]$ is finite, then $G$ is virtually cyclic by definition. We conclude in particular $[G, G]$ and $G/[G, G]$ are both infinite f.g. groups.

We now do as in the third item in my question (I explain the general trick though of course here we could simplify a bit): Pick a bi-infinite injective path $p$ in some Cayley graph of $[G, G]$ with some finite set of generators $S \subset G$ and pick another one $q$ in the Cayley graph of $G/[G, G]$ with some finite set of generators $T$. Pick for each $t \in T$ a preimage in $G$, i.e. $s_t \in G$ such that $t = [G, G] s_t$. Now the path $s_q$ defined in the obvious way by lifting $q$ (if $q$ is a sequence over $\mathbb{Z}$ of generators $t \in T$, pick the corresponding path along generators $s_t$) is injective as a path in $G$, since even its projection to $G/[G, G]$ is by definition injective. Now, start the path $p$ from each vertex on the path $s_q$, and observe that these paths do not intersect themselves (since $p$ does not), and they do not intersect each other since their projections in $G/[G, G]$ stay inside distinct cosets.

That concludes the proof.